# Is standardized scaling a pre-requisite for applying PCA using sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, centering, pca

I have a set of 70 input variables on which I need to perform PCA. As per my understanding centering data such that for each input variable mean is `0` and variance is `1`, is necessary for applying PCA.

I am having a hard time figuring it out that do I need to perform standard scaling `preprocessing.StandardScaler()`before passing my data set to `PCA` or `PCA` function in sklearn does it on its own.

If latter is the case then irrespective of if I do, or do not apply `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` the `explained_variance_ratio_` should be the same.

But the results are different, hence I believe `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` is necessary before applying `PCA`. Is it true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it' true, `scikit-learn`'s PCA does not apply standardization to the input dataset, it only centers it by  [subtracting the mean](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L434).

See also this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235882/pca-in-numpy-and-sklearn-produces-different-results).